# Do creating value based on current state or based on defined value inside reducer makes a pure function impure?

Tags: redux, pure-function

I read on `redux-devtools` [walkthrough](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-devtools/blob/890ecf8b56c4ac2036491edfcf9ca77cab859a1d/docs/Walkthrough.md):

> Your reducers have to be pure and free of side effects to work correctly with
>   DevTools. For example, **even generating a random ID in reducer makes it
>   impure and non-deterministic**. Instead, do this in action creators.

Those words says about **generating random** value. But, how about taking
unique values based on current state? For example, by taking array's length
as an ID for elements when storing data to current state. As long as I'm not
removing any value of the array, it guaranteed to be unique. Do this
makes a function impure?

Or, by creating conditional value based on current state like this:

```
function reducer (state, action) {
    if (state.isLocked) return state;
    // calculate further
}
```

Or, more extreme, by having a defined value that only exist inside a function
like:

```
{ type: 'CREATE_USER', age: 13 }

// it is predictable, always return the same value with same argument
function getAgeText(age) {
  if (age < 5) return 'baby';
  if (age < 20) return 'teenager';
  if (age < 30) return 'mature';
  if (age < 40) return 'old';
  if (age < 50) return 'very old';
  return 'astounding';
} // of course by assuming we have to use this function in case you
  // ask, "Why don't get those values anywhere else and not in
  // this reducer?"

function reducer (state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'CREATE_USER':
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        age: age, ageText: getAgeText(action.age)
      });
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

So, is those examples make function impure? And, if not, is it a bad practice
in redux to create a long, complex calculation or heavily nested reducer
even if it is done only from the passed value (state and action)?

Answer (score 0):

Both reducer functions are deterministic, because they always will return same new states based on same current states.